# Let $f:R\to R$ a continuous function and $F$ a primitive of $f$. Prove that there is no $a,b \in R^*$ so $f(ax+bF(x))=ax+b$, $\forall x\in R$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

Assuming that a and b exists:
$F(ax+bF(x))=\int f(ax+bF(x))(a+bf(x))dx+C=\int (ax+b)(a+bf(x))dx=a^2{x^2/2}+abx+b^2F(x)+ab\int xf(x) dx+C$
I know that I have to find a contradiction, or maybe a value of x for which this relationship is not true, but I am stuck at this point. I would be extremely grateful for any ideas. thank you.

Comment: By $R^*$ in the title, do you just mean the real numbers?

Comment: Non-zero real numbers

Comment: The question on the contents and  on the title are different.  [f or F?]  And use $$ to make math notation in the title.

Comment: Well, in the content I used that $F(u(x))=\int f(u(x))u'(x)dx+C$ of course, for $F$ a primitive of $f$. That is why $F(ax+bF(x))=\int f(ax+bF(x)(a+bf(x))dx+C.$ Assuming that $f(ax+bF(x))=ax+b$ I obtained the following equality. I might not understand your misunderstanding though. @LevBahn

Comment: @Georgia Oh sorry!  I misunderstood. If you put $$ in your title, it would be perfect.